# Inconsistent Sequelize query construct for custom query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am currently trying to construct a Sequelize query in my node application as shown below;

```
import sequelize from 'sequelize';

function getReadMsg(){
  const where = [sequelize.where(
    sequelize.literal('"Message"."status" = \'read\'') 
  )];

  const attributes = { exclude: ['updated_at'] };

  const order = [['created_at', 'ASC']];

  return model.findAll({ where, attributes, order }); // model is a sequelize model object
}
```

However, the Sequelize's constructed raw query is comparing the
**where** block to null, therefore defeating the purpose of the query.

Below is the raw Sequelize constructed query;

```
SELECT "id", "title", "body", "to", "from", "status", "created_at" FROM "Messages" AS "Message" WHERE ("Message"."status" = 'read' IS NULL) ORDER BY "Message"."created_at" ASC;
```

Instead of;

```
SELECT "id", "title", "body", "to", "from", "status", "created_at" FROM "Messages" AS "Message" WHERE ("Message"."status" = 'read') ORDER BY "Message"."created_at" ASC;
```

squelize version: 5.21.4.

squelize-cli version: 5.5.1.

node version: 12.16.1

Comment: Please use something like https://sqlformat.org/ to format your SQL queries.

Comment: @Anatoly, I would look into that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sequelize.where` uses 3 parameters and if you omit the 2 last ones they will be '=' and 'null' respectively.
You should do something like this:

```
sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('"Message"."status"'), '=', 'read')
```